# How to add a custom button on KeyboardDatePicker

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

The ability to customize the actions at the bottom of the KeyboardDatePicker.
For example: add a new button for current date selection (CURRENT button).
check the example image:

[image]

Comment: Issue solved !!

Comment: We can use "showToday" props to get the today button and then can add todayLabel = 'Current' props to rename it to current button.